# HTML form passing array of options as the values to the checklist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'd like to figure a way out using html and javascript. I have a form which will get modified each week and would like to simplify editing it.

```
events_in = ["event_1_date", "event_2_date", etc...]
```

and would display the check boxes

```
[] event_1_date  
[] event_2_date
```

which you can then use the form normally.

The array input to form values will get updated weekly with new events.

There is a way using php but couldn't translate it into the languages I want to use.

Comment: did you try anything yet?

Comment: Yes, I used rwacarter solution.

Comment: sarcasm? this is not a website where usually people code for free, for you, from scratch, it's always better to start from some code you tried before. that's also why wour question received two "close" flags

Comment: The only thing I used was '<div id="checkboxes"></div>' and '$('#checkboxes').append(' since I'm using bootstrap for my form the rest of it was just aditional information. I'm sorry you feel that I just ask people to code for free. I just needed a hint of how to do a task I have been just copying and pasting and would like to simplify the process. Also, how come I found a php equivalent with like 20 up votes and couldn't find anything in js and your giving me a hard time.

Comment: I'm still in school and am still learning the programming trade and don't have a lot of knowledge on js programming. Also, I thought this was a website where you could ask question about programming tips/tricks and then repay the favor by answering other people's questions?

Comment: It is as you said, but there's always at least a right and a wrong way to ask questions. Usually a correct way is: "I have this problem [....] I tried this stuff [....], but I still have problems [....], can you help me?" and usually including some code speeds up the answering process. Naturally these are general guidelines, but since you're learning (as almost everyone here!), they could be useful to know. Moreover, you learn more by trying and failing (then asking for help) than asking for code directly :) lecture over, good learning!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery (as you have included the `jQuery` tag).. First add a div to your form:

```
<div id="checkboxes"></div>
```

Then in javascript:

```
$(function() {

    var events_in = ["event_1_date", "event_2_date"],
        events_in_count = events_in.length,
        i = 0;

    for(;i<events_in_count;i++) {

        $('#checkboxes').append('<label><input type="checkbox" name="' + events_in[i] + '">' + events_in[i] + '</label>');

    }

});
```

Comment: Looks clean and simple. I'll give it a shot as soon as my classes finish. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this.

```js
var one = "text here";
var two = "text here"
var array = [["one", one],["two",two]]

window.onload = init;

function init(){
 var checkListItems = document.querySelectorAll(".checklist-items");

 for(var i = 0; i < checkListItems.length; i++){
  updateHTML(checkListItems[i]);
 }
}

function updateHTML(item){
 var id = item.getAttribute("id");
 alert(id)

 for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
  if(array[i][0] == id){
   item.innerHTML = array[i][1];
  }
 }

}
```

```html
<form action="">
 <input type="checkbox"><span class="checklist-items" id="one">Item</span>
 <input type="checkbox"><span class="checklist-items" id="two">Item</span>
 <input type="checkbox"><span class="checklist-items" id="three">Item</span>
 <input type="checkbox"><span class="checklist-items" id="four">Item</span>
 <input type="checkbox"><span class="checklist-items" id="five">Item</span>
</form>
```